# Removing strings within an html element duplicate content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My initial HTML looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coh-container coh-container-boxed">
   <p class="coh-paragraph">Up until about five years ago, only low levels of AI or machine learning were being used for some fraud-detection tasks. And then a few early-adopter CSPs started to apply modern machine-learning tools to revenue assurance and fraud management with very positive results, which has encouraged more and more CSPs to adopt machine learning as part of business-assurance best practices.<br>
      <br>
      &nbsp;<br>
      <br>
      But what’s next for machine learning?<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      Will it become an out-of-the-box solution?<br>
      &nbsp;<br>
      Can machine-learning self-tuning outwit changes in fraudsters’ behavior?<br>
      &nbsp;<br>
      What are the myths about applying machine learning to business assurance, and what’s the reality?<br>
      &nbsp;<br>
      Can business assurance support 5G and all the new risks that come with it?<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      Watch this masterclass video from TM Forum Digital Transformation World 2020, with experts from BT, Rogers Communications, A1, and Deutsche Telekom, discussing these and other critical issues with Amdocs CVidya CTO Dr Gadi Solotorevsky.<br>
      <br>
      .zoom:hover { <br>
      transform: scale(1.02);  <br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      .zoom {<br>
      <br>
      transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */<br>
      width: 100%;<br>
      height: 100%;<br>
      margin: 0 auto;<br>
      background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.2)!important;<br>
      border-radius: 15px;<br>
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);<br>
      } <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      .col-lg-6 {<br>
      <br>
      height:270px;<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      .relatedtype {<br>
      height:30px;<br>
      font-size:large;<br>
      padding:15px 15px 0px 15px!important;<br>
      font-weight:bold;<br>
      font-size:small;<br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      .relatedtitle {<br>
      height:100px;<br>
      font-size:large;<br>
      padding:15px 15px 0px 15px!important;<br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      .relateddesc {<br>
      height:160px;<br>
      <br>
      padding:0px 15px 5px 15px!important;<br>
      <br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      .linesmall {<br>
      height: 4px;<br>
      background: linear-gradient(to right,#ffa402,#ff5661,#ff279c);<br>
      width: 32px;<br>
      display: block;<br>
      padding:2px 2px 2px 15px!important; <br>
      margin-bottom:20px;<br>
      margin-left:15px;<br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      .related {<br>
      overflow: hidden;<br>
      text-align: center;<br>
      margin-top:30px!important;<br>
      margin-bottom:50px!important;<br>
      font-size:24px!important;<br>
      font-weight:bold;<br>
      line-height:1.1<br>
      <br>
      }<br>
      .related:before,<br>
      .related:after {<br>
      /*background-color: #323147;*/<br>
      background: linear-gradient(to right,#ffa402,#ff5661,#ff279c);<br>
      content: "";<br>
      display: inline-block;<br>
      height: 2px;<br>
      position: relative;<br>
      vertical-align: middle;<br>
      width: 50%;<br>
      }<br>
      .related:before {<br>
      right: 0.5em;<br>
      margin-left: -50%;<br>
      }<br>
      .related:after {<br>
      left: 0.5em;<br>
      margin-right: -50%;<br>
      }<br>
      <br>
      next steps<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      insight<br>
      <br>
      Executive predictions 2021<br>
      <br>
      &nbsp;<br>
      <br>
      How COVID-19, 5G, cloud and more are changing our world<br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      solutions<br>
      <br>
      Amdocs cVidya<br>
      <br>
      &nbsp;<br>
      <br>
      Protect your business to enable growth
   </p>
   <p class="coh-paragraph">Summary<br><br>
      <br><br>
      Amdocs cVidya CTO Gadi Solotorevsky leads a TM Forum masterclass on machine learning as part of business-assurance best practices
   </p>
   <div class="coh-row coh-row-xs coh-row-visible-xs" data-coh-row-match-heights="{&quot;xs&quot;:{&quot;target&quot;:&quot;none&quot;}}">
      <div class="coh-row-inner coh-style-center-content">
         <div class="coh-column coh-visible-xs coh-col-xs-12 coh-visible-md coh-col-md-10">
            <div class="coh-container coh-container-boxed">      </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Problem: There is css within the markup that cannot show, and we're talking about over 400 pages. So, I decided to use JS to find each css line and detach from the DOM or replace with empty string.

The JS attempt looks like the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
   var content = document.querySelector('.coh-paragraph').textContent
  .replace(".zoom:hover {", "")
  .replace("transform: scale(1.02);", "")
  .replace("}", "")
  .replace(".zoom {", "")
  .replace("transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */", "")
  .replace("width: 100%;", "")
  .replace("height: 100%;", "")
  .replace("margin: 0 auto;", "")
  .replace("background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.2)!important;", "")
  .replace("border-radius: 15px;", "")
  .replace("box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);", "")
  .replace("}", "")
   
   $('.coh-paragraph').detach()
  
   var newParagraph = document.createElement("p")
   newParagraph.classList.add("new-paragraph");
  
   newParagraph.textContent = content
  
   console.log("Text content")
   console.log(newParagraph)
  
  var pContainer = document.querySelector('.coh-container')
  // pContainer.innerHTML += newParagraph
  console.log(pContainer)
  
  $(".coh-container").append(newParagraph);
  
  

});
```

However, this does not seem to be partially working because it's all the b tags are now removed, and for some reason the text is duplicated.

How can I remove all the css from the page programatically?

Comment: How do you end up with css text mixed with content text in the first place? Looks like a scraping job that needs to be fixed at the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try with regex in JS.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/johna138/pen/jOBxBLe

```
const p = document.querySelector("p.coh-paragraph");

// This does not keep the <br /> tags.
p.textContent = p.textContent.replace(/.*(?<=\s)[^ ]*\s*\{[^\}]+\:[^\}]+\}/gm, "");

// This keeps all the <br /> tags
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/.*(?<=\s)[^ ]*\s*\{[^\}]+\:[^\}]+\}/gm, "");
```

Comment: may you please explain the regex?
I see that it does part of the work. However, it still removes all the b tags

Comment: Sure I'll try my best to explain!
https://regex101.com/r/57Mz4B/1 - this breaks down the regex in more detail.

`.*` checks if the beginning of the line starts with a `.` followed by any character.

`(?<=\s)` is known as a [positive lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) - This checks everything behind the open braces.

` [^ ]*` - matches a single character not present in the brackets (in this case a space).

`\s*` - matches any whitespace before the open braces.

`\{` - check for the open brace.

`^\}]+\:[^\}]` - check for the closed brace.

Comment: A lot to learn about regex. Is it possible to edit your snippet in a way that it only removes the css and not group all the text together without the br tags? Because it now put everything together.

Comment: If you want to keep the `br` tags you will need to use `.innerHTML`

`p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/.*(?<=\s)[^ ]*\s*\{[^\}]+\:[^\}]+\}/g, "");`